# C# populate toolstripmenu item in run-time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add submenu into the main menu in runtime.  I have looked at other post 
[Adding to strip menu at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590395/adding-to-strip-menu-at-run-time)  but I don't understand what I'm missing here because it only populates one item, but I have three xml files in the folder. Below is the code.  testsuite paramenter contains xml files.

```
    public void LoadTestSuiteMenuStrip(string[] testsuite)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var temp in testsuite)
            {
                int max = temp.Length-1;
                while (temp[max] != '\\')
                    max--;

                max++;

                //remove the folder path and take only xml file name
                string name = temp.Substring(max, temp.Length - max);

                ToolStripMenuItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(name);
                //subItem.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
                //subItem .Text = name;
                //subItem .Name = name;
                //subItem.Tag = name;
                subItem.Click += new EventHandler(testSuiteToolstrip_Click);
                testsuiteToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: 1. remove `try .. catch` block and see if there is any exception; 2. use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` method to get file name from full path.

Comment: thanks, after removing the try &catch, it gives me error after adding one submenu to the the main menu. The error for cross-threading calling error.   LoadTestSuiteMenuStrip() is different thread from main GUI.  But not sure why the exception threw so late, after one submenu.

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFileName() is very handy. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you access GUI from main thread. If you want to add items from other thread, instead of

```
LoadTestSuiteMenuStrip(args);
```

use

```
Invoke(new Action<string[]>(LoadTestSuiteMenuStrip), new object[] { args });
```